# In Yii2, how can I exclude layout from rendering in a view file?

Tags: php, yii2

I have an admin login page that I want to render without the layout. How can I render a view in Yii2 without rendering the main layout?

Comment: It can be done only in controller with method renderPartial

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This can be done using `renderPartial()` method.

You can get more from the official documentation. Here's [a link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial()-detail)!

Comment: What about rendering a file within a view? renderPartial() is not a view method. and $this->context->renderPartial() looks ugly

Answer (score 18):

In your controller you can assing layout for all actions of controller or turn it off:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
//  public $layout='//admin';
  public $layout=false;
```

OR you can do it for only one action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
  $this->layout = false;
```

Comment: This worked for me, in my case I wanted to keep the Assets to let jquery works on view so I created a new layout file without logo and headers and assing it as your example 
`public function actionIndex()
{
  $this->layout = 'mynewlayout';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `renderPartial` to exclude header and footer of layout from view file. However if you `renderPartial` it will not load asset files (css and js files). To load asset files without layout you can use `renderAjax`.