# Yii2 Ajax returns whole page content

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I am trying to make simple ajax :

```
$('.send-contact-button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

       var id = $('.send-contact-button').data('id');
       var flag = $('.send-contact-button').data('flag');

       $.ajax({
           method : 'GET',
           url : "contactHandler?id="+id+"&flag="+flag,
           success : function( data ){
                console.log( data );
           }
       });

    });
```

but every time i get the html content. Tryied to send the data through json but without result. This Ajax is just test.
Controller:

```
public function contactHandler($id, $flag)
{
    echo $id;
}
```

Can you guys tell me where i am wrong ? Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361782/in-yii2-how-can-i-exclude-layout-from-rendering-in-a-view-file

Comment: No it is not :) I do not want to render a partial view just to get the `$id` in the console :)

Comment: What is HTML content that you get then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ajax call should be formatted using yii2 urlmanager rules (`contact-handler` instead of `contactHandler`

```
  $.ajax({
       method : 'GET',
       url : "contact-handler?id="+id+"&flag="+flag,
       success : function( data ){
            console.log( data );
       }
   });
```

and in your controller you must add the action text to your function name
eg:`public function actionContactHandler($id, $flag)`

Answer (score 1):

Your action is not defined correctly, you are probably getting an error page.

try this:

```
public function actionContactHandler($id, $flag)
{
    echo $id;
}
```